# Form designer in VS2013 Zoomed in?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

Just upgraded to windows 8 and loaded on VS2013, opened up a quick new project (winforms) and created a 2 min, quick UI..

Just noticed when I've built/run the app that the form in design mode appears larger than the form when its actually Started.

Screen shot below.

Ive never had this before? Form designer has always been relative to the executable running.

Have I set something up wrong does anyone know?

Form seems really big in the designer?

My screen res is 1440x900.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I don't have VS2013 in front of me, so just a guess. Perhaps it's down to display settings then.

Comment: The OP has a WinForms project - there's no zoom box on WinForms designer windows.

Comment: Have you got your Windows text size set to bigger than 100%? (Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display) If so, the Visual Studio designer might be scaling things differently to your application when it's running.

Comment: Just checked, making the Windows text size larger makes no difference.

Comment: Hi all, I've checked everything everyone has suggested, but to no avail. All my settings seem correct, really strange!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I did resolve this issue in the end, but it was a strange "fix". I check my Display settings and the section "Change the size of all items" was set to 100% (default), but in VS my form designer would still be working to a different scale it appeared.

I changed the size/scale in Display to 125% and that brought the VS form in design mode in-line (size-wise) to the form when running, but obviously both were now running scaled up to 125% which was way to large. I then returned the Display setting back to 100% default and when I opened VS I noticed instantly the scale seemed correct. And thankfully now my forms in designer were the same scale as my forms when running. Its almost as though VS was picking up an incorrect setting(s) and the Display setting just needed refreshing.

I dont think this was a fluke for me as I have had the exact same issue over 4 recent fresh builds of VS 2013 on different machines across Windows 8 and 8.1. All had this same issue.

Just thought i'd share my experience incase it helps anyone else in the future - very random issue to encounter!

Comment: So you toggled the system DPI settings back and forth, and that fixed it? When you install VS, what DPI settings do you have active? If you can consistently repro this, it might be a bug.

Comment: I found the same problem on VS2015, as well as changing the scaling I had to log out and back in again.

Comment: Just to add on some occasions I have had to reboot to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using 1080p laptop display and 1440p monitor. No "Change the size of items" helped. VS somehow remembered the settings from 1440p monitor on 1080p laptop display - even without the connected 1440p. 
All I had to do was to connect the laptop to 1440p monitor and move the vs window from 1080p to 1440p and back to 1080p. Now the scale seems fine.